# UIImagePickerController, application exit when clicking cancel button on right top of photo album screen on selecting a image

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickerController, application exit when clicking cancel button on right top of photo album screen on selecting a image.

```
-(void) getImageAction:(id) sender 
{
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    if([sender tag] == 0) 
    {

         if (![[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"] && ![[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPod touch"]) {
             imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Camera Not available in your device");
             return;
         }
    } 
    else 
    {
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    NSLog(@"image picker method called");
    // Dismiss the image selection, hide the picker and show the image view with the picked image
    [imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //imagePickerController.view.hidden = YES;


    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(40, 5, 200, 200);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addSubview: imageView];
    [self.view addSubview: messageText];
    [self.view addSubview: sendGreet];
    [fromGallery removeFromSuperview];
    [fromCamera removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I, your method `-(void) getImageAction:(id) sender` add `[imagePickerController release];` in the end. When ever you are using `presentModalViewController`, you got to release the controller you are moving to.

In general the application crashes when there is a memory leak or unknown identifier send to some method.

Hope this works for you!!